# Heic instead of hic in a Maltese tomb

Tags: new-latin, spelling, inscription

Continuing my series of questions about Malta ([locative vs. *in*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6554/79) and [*monumentum/monimentum*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6561/79)), I would like to ask about an inscription I saw in [St. John's co-cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_John%27s_Co-Cathedral) in Valletta.

The floor was tiled with tombstones with inscriptions in Latin.
The one in the picture below starts: *Heic in pulvere dormit fr[ater] Hieronymus de nobilibus Cataciensis qui omnibus equitis religiosi numeris absolutus gravissima sacro ordini praestitit…*

[image: A tombstone in Latin]

What immediately caught my attention is the first word *heic*, which seems to stand for *hic*, "here".
Is this variation common?
Does it already appear in older Latin, or is it a medieval or later thing?
I think this tomb is from the 18th century although the date is just outside the frame.

(If you have trouble parsing the text, please ask a separate question!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right: [***heic***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dheic) is an archaic form of the adverb [***hīc***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dhic).

See the latter entry at III.2:

> hīc (old form heic; and with the interrog. part. ne, hicine ), adv. loci, *in this place, here.*

A corpus search reveals 0 results for that form. I did find at least one other inscription from Spain that uses the same form:

> heus viator si ulla tibi / pietas inest verte huc / ora / heic sunt cineres c canii / poetae qui ad quart us/que olimp in urbe omnib / karus vix deinde in hispan / revers nemin laes tand / cum ad veteres cuper sodal / in latium remeare per/petuoq cum populo quir / viv dura nimium fata prae/ripuere et in itin occub / l albinus cit hisp proc hoc / marmore texit

Comment: If it's an archaic form, why is it showing up in the 18th century?

Comment: Deliberate antiquarianism is the only reasonable answer. And the less commonplace Latin was becoming, I'd assume, the more latitude for idiosyncrasy.