# Abbreviation "D. O. M." on tombstones

Tags: new-latin, abbreviations, inscription

To finish my Maltese question series before boarding a plane off the island, here is another question about [Latin inscriptions in tombstones in St. John's co-cathedral at Valletta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6571/79).
In many tombs, including the one below, the inscription begins with the abbreviation "D. O. M." in a fashion very similar to Roman grave inscriptions starting with "D. M." much earlier.

What does this abbreviation mean?
I did not find any graves with this abbreviation expanded (starting with three words with initial letters DOM).
I assume it is a Christian counterpart of the Roman *Dis Manibus* and that the D stands for some form of *Deus*.
Is "D. O. M." related to "D. M." at all, or is the similarity a complete coincidence?

[image: A tombstone in Latin]

Comment: Aha, they were programmers! _Document Object Model_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Google search gives results for both *Domino* and *Deo Optimo Maximo*. However the former offers results for both, suggesting it is a variation of the latter.

> **Deo Optimo Maximo**,

in turn, has its own [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deo_optimo_maximo) and seems to be the preferred form. According to the article,

> ***Deo optimo maximo***, often abbreviated D.O.M. or Deo Opt. Max., is a Latin phrase which means "to the greatest and best god", or "to God, most good, most great". It was originally used as a pagan formula addressed to Jupiter. [And later adopted by Christianity.]

It dates from antiquity and is also common in ancient tombstones in Rome, both Christian and pagan. I recall seeing a lot of them in the *scavi Vaticani*.

Answer (score 6):

Deo (or Domino) Optimo Maximo. It is the motto of the Benedictine order.