# Can I conclude something about pronunciation from I/J and U/V variation?

Tags: pronunciation, new-latin, spelling, inscription

I reread the inscription [in this question about the abbreviation D. O. M.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6573/79) dated to 1749:

[image: An inscription from Malta.]

The variation between I and J caught my eye.
It seems to me that:

- J is used in all consonantal positions.
- J is used in *hujus*.
- J is used after I: *varijs, munijs, junij*.
- In all other positions I is used, whether it is (classically) short or long.

U and V behave in a similar way:
U is used in all vocalic positions, V in all consonantal ones.
The only (perhaps) exception is that after Q we always have U.

The spelling choices seem very consistent, so I can't attribute this to chance.
This seems to suggest that the U after Q is pronounced as a vowel, and the J in *hujus, varijs, munijs, junij* is pronounced as a consonant.
**Is this conclusion justified?**
All other make sense to me, but *varijs, munijs, junij* sound weird to me.
Is it indeed a matter of spelling convention where no two consecutive Is can appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your conclusions is, I feel, justified: that the *j* in *hujus* is due to it being pronounced as a consonant/semivowel, since that was always the case. More than that: from Classical times (and actually earlier than that) almost all instances of consonantal *i* between vowels were geminated, since intervocalic short /j/ was lost at an earlier stage (e.g. PIE *tréyes > Proto-Italic *trēs; the exceptions are all compound words where the second part starts with /j/), so *huius* was /ˈhuj.jus/. This is still the case in Church Latin today (/ˈuj.jus/), so the only question to my mind isn't about *j*, but if the *h* is pronounced or not (presumably not).

*ii* being written as *ij* I wouldn't consider evidence of anything other than a desire to be easier to read. At least since the Middle Ages people have occasionally (and at points frequently) written the final *i* in Roman numerals ending in runs of them as *j*, and in, for example, Middle Dutch /iː/ came to be written [<ij>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(digraph)) rather than <ii> for aesthetic reasons as well. It's just a common ligature.

*qu* has always been an odd duck, but I see no reason to believe the *u* there suggests that that part of the sound came to be pronounced as a vowel so much as that it *didn't* become fricative like consonantal *u* in other positions; i.e. the normal state of affairs.